# choosing floating point calculation model

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

my question is mainly for scientific computations but I am asking in general. How do you practically choose fp model in compiler ? for example intel has precise, strict, fast, extended, source, double etc.

Answer (score 0):

The GCC wiki has a writeup on various floating-point optimizations at http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath

Comment: Yes but understanding how floating point computation really works is a little hard. So is there any best practice (e.g. in scientific computation world we should always use double and strict model etc) ?

Comment: Understanding floating point computation deeply is not a little hard, it's very hard. And, there's no shortcut, sorry. The best practice is to thoroughly understand FP computation as well as your algorithm and then be able to make an informed decision wrt. how strict one needs to be for each particular algorithm. In practice, many don't bother with all that and just hope that whatever they're using is good enough.